# Javascript activate the clicked element by className

Tags: javascript

I am trying to loop through the `items` array and whichever element has been *clicked*, then apply functionality to it. 

For example:

```
var items = getElementsByClassName("media-item");

addEventListener("click", function() {

  for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if(items[i].onclick) {
      items[i].classList.toggle("show-media-item");
      items[i].getElementsByTagName("figcaption")[0].classList.toggle("show-caption");
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: That's not how you do that...

Comment: You should [read the addEventListener docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) - event handlers are added to _one_ element. You should define one function to do the `classList` toggling then iterate items and attach the event handler to each: `items[i].addEventListener('click', classToggler);`